# How to ask a relative clause to describe an object that is marked with に。

Tags: grammar, particle-に, relative-clauses

OK so I understand that to say "He is lying to me", you would say:

> 彼は私に嘘をついている。

My question is how would i say "The person he is lying to is me."

or from "I gave the book to my brother"

> 兄さんに本をあげた。

"the person who i gave the book to is my older brother"

Comment: Japanese relative clause is simpler than the English equivalent, but can be ambiguous, too. 本をあげた人は兄さんだ can mean both "The person who I gave the book is my brother" (兄さん = receiver) and "The person who gave the book (to someone else) is my brother" (兄さん = giver) depending on the context.